# Cannot hard reset Huawei P9 (Reset failed)

Tags: huawei

Recently my Huawei P9 somehow got updated to EMUI 5.0, and everything was going well except the updater setting and camera app was gone and the flashlight would not turn on. I decided to backup my data and perform a factory reset. However, the reset failed and when I turned it on the only keyboard installed was Google Voice Typing and I coudn't use it because I'm Asian and it woudn't recognize what I said. I tried skipping all the steps but it seemed to be stuck at "checking info". After countless times of resetting it i found out I could connect to wifi when I reset it from eRecovery. After doing so, I installed a keyboard using the built in SD card. I tried to use ADB but it only managed to connect once and I made a typo and I cound't connect again. I tried rolling it back but I simply coudn't get past the factory reset stage. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I unlocked the bootloader and flashed TWRP onto my device(though I'm not sure if the failed reset removed it).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just had to skip the intermediate package and jump to the stock firmware.

EDIT: On the official page, to downgrade, it states to flash an intermediate firmware. The fix was to simply skip it and flash the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Reflash the stock firmware. If you have a recovery installed then format the data and system partition and then flash the rom that you like. Or you can just make a **dload**  folder in your sdcard ,put the stock firmware for your device and then boot by pressing all the keys of your device (**Volume Up + Volume Down + Power**). It will make your device do a forced update.